# Create a large bitset

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, bitset

I need to use a bitset of size 400000000. Just like this:

```
 #include<iostream>

 #include<bitset>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){
 bitset<400000000> coord;}
```

But my program crashes because the bitset is too large. So how can I dynamically allocate a bitset? I can't use boost library.

Comment: You might consider the much-maligned `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: I can't use that because I'm using bitset to create an array of booleans with size 8 times less the normal

Comment: @JerryCoffin you should never consider `std::vector<bool>` (it is not a container).

Comment: @mookid: Sorry, but nonsense. You don't always need a container. Bitset isn't a container either, and nothing else that stores Booleans as a single bit can be. In short, the disadvantages of `std::vector<bool>` will apply just as much to any alternative he picks.

Answer (score 3):

You can allocate the memory in the heap with new. The heap is much larger than the stack. Code below.

```
 #include<iostream>

 #include<bitset>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){
    bitset<400000000UL>* coord_ptr = new bitset<400000000UL>();
    bitset<400000000UL> coord = *coord_ptr;
    // <~~ do stuff ~~>
    delete coord_ptr;
 }
```

Comment: But then my program crashes when I do something like:                    #include<iostream>

 #include<bitset>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){
   bitset<400000000> *coord = new bitset<400000000>;
   coord[8]=1;
 }

Comment: Try this instead:  bitset<4000000UL>& coord = *(new bitset<4000000UL>()); I am not sure why this is different but when I compile it it runs fine.

Comment: Please don't actually use this code for anything, that there is a giant memoryleak.